# unknown error causing the app to crash

Tags: java, android

I am trying to populate an arraylist with three variable. After that the arraylist should display its content in a listview. when i run this class logcat shows an error which is completely unknown to me. Following is the class I am using.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Secondscreen extends Activity {

String pName ;
int pPrice;
String pDisc;
int total;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen); 
    ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    //TextView showCartContent    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showCart);
    final Button thirdBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.third);
    //final LinearLayout lb = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.secondLinear);

    final Controller aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

            final int cartSize = aController.getCart().getCartSize();

            final ArrayList<Listitem> arrayList=new ArrayList<Listitem>();


            BaseAdapter adapter= new BaseAdapter(){

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return arrayList.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return arrayList.get(position);
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return 0;
                }

                LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
                    if (view == null) {
                        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pattern, null);
                    }
                    TextView tv=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameview);
                    TextView tv2=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdesc);
                    TextView tv3=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priceView);
                    tv.setText(pName);
                    tv2.setText(pPrice);
                    tv3.setText(pDisc);
                    return view;
                }       

            };
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);


            if(cartSize >0)
                {   

                    for(int i=0;i<cartSize;i++)
                    {

                        pName   = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductName();
                        pPrice      = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductPrice();
                        pDisc       = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductDesc();

                        Listitem item=new Listitem(pName, pPrice,pDisc);
                        arrayList.add(item);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                }

}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();


 }
}
```

Please Help me to solve this.

Comment: please copy paste your log in question, not able to read it in image

Comment: The error is not readable!! Please post the "CausedBy" line from logCat. Also try setting adapter(  lv.setAdapter(adapter)) AFTER this if block: if(cartSize >0)

Comment: please show your Logcat clearly, However you are retrieving array value after setting adapter which is wrong do its reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tv2.setText(pPrice);
```

pPrice is a int. setText(int) looks for a String id inside the R classes throwing a ResourceNotFoundException if the look-up fails. A quick fix is

```
tv2.setText(""+pPrice);
```

This way you are providing a `String` object to `setText`

Edit:

Change your getView this way:

```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
         if (view == null) {
                    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pattern, null);
          }
          Listitem item = (Listitem)getItem(position)
          TextView tv=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameview);
          TextView tv2=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdesc);
          TextView tv3=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priceView);
          tv.setText(item. pName);
          tv2.setText(""+item.pPrice);
          tv3.setText(item.pDisc);
          return view;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks blackbelt. Your previous solution worked. Now I am having another problem with the code.please help me in solving that. Please read the post above.

Comment: My main post at the top of this page.

Comment: you should not change the question this way. Otherwise my answer seems meaningless. You should restore the original question and either open a new question or add an "edit" section to the original one

Comment: Restored it. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You never get your objects from the ArrayList. Add this code to your getView() method:

```
ListItem item = arrayList.get(position);
tv.setText(item.pName);
tv2.setText(item.pPrice);
tv3.setText(item.pDisc);
```